# Executes other form periodically

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-4.5

In Vb.net, I want to show my main form and other form periodically.
The last form does check operations and automatically closes.
Should be implementing threads, but I am not sure if it's possible...

My code is empty..

```
Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Friend NotInheritable Class Program

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    <STAThread() _
    Shared Sub Main()
        Application.EnableVisualStyles()
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false)
        Application.Run (New formMain()) '--> Main Form

        'All code here is not execute until Main Form is closed

    End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Sorry, I am a newbie in vb.net, I would want to say show my main form.

---

Edit 2: I think I didn't explain well, but with the help of @JeremyThompson I can complete my code.

FormMain: Now, When I try to close this form, I show another form to do check operations but I hold this (FormMain) always visible.

```
 Private Sub FormMain_FormClosing(sender as Object, e as FormClosingEventArgs) _ 
     Handles FormMain.FormClosing

    Me.Visible = True

    Dim anotherForm as New CheckOperationsForm()
    anotherForm.Show()

    e.Cancel = True
```

End Sub

Other form (or FormCheckOperations()): When the routine coded in this form is completed I establish the value of a boolean _successfulChecking, so if this boolean is true, main form keeps on showing, in another case, the application ends.

```
Private Sub FormCheckOperations_FormClosing(sender as Object, e as FormClosingEventArgs) _ 
     Handles FormCheckOperations.FormClosing

    If Not _succesfulChecking Then
        End 'Close application
    End If

End Sub
```

My doubt is, how I can show FormCheckOperation periodically from MainForm (I could call FormMain.Close() to do it) or how do it from Main Sub?

---

Edit 3: Now, In my current approach, I open 2 threads in Main Sub, the first one with the Main Form and the second one with another thread which opens CheckOperations Forms each 60 seconds. But when executes in Visual Studio, forms stay "behind" of the SDK, furthermore, they are not working properly, but I think the final way should be closer.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Friend NotInheritable Class Program

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    <STAThread() _
    Shared Sub Main()
        Application.EnableVisualStyles()
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false)

        Dim threadFormMain As New Thread (AddressOf launchFrmMain)
        Dim threadFormCheckOperations As New Thread (AddressOf launchThreadFrmCheckOperations)

        threadFormMain.Start()
        threadFormCheckOperations.Start()

    End Sub


    Public Shared Sub launchFrmMain()
        Application.Run(New FormMain()
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub launchThreadFrmCheckOperations()
         While(True)
             Dim threadForm As New Thread(AddressOf launchFrmCheckOperations)
             threadForm.Start()
             'Here I should stop while loop during 60 secs…
             'Thread.Sleep(60000)
         End While
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub launchFrmCheckOperations()
        Application.Run(New FormCheckOperations()
    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: does `execute my form` mean show it?

Comment: ...so display the other form periodically from the main form (using a Timer maybe)?  What exactly do you need help with here?

Comment: But when I show de main form, main thread stay locked… I am wondering about the idea of how I could do it. Thanks!

Comment: Regarding Edit 2, whats the other condition for showing FormCheckOperation *periodically* other than FormMain's close event?

Comment: Really, I don't understand what you mean. Now, I am searching solution from Sub Main (in my Program.vb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this.
In Main Sub firstly launches a thread with check operation forms (globally declared)  and later launches mainForm in main thread.
The thread with check operations contains while loop which creates a new thread in each iteration, but with Thread.Join() stays waiting the end of previous thread, so it avoids to create other thread while there is a thread opened.

The code is the following:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Friend NotInheritable Class Program

Private Sub New()
End Sub

<STAThread() _
Shared Sub Main()
    Application.EnableVisualStyles()
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false)

    threadFormCheckOperations.Start()

    Application.Run(New FormMain())

End Sub

Public Shared threadFormCheckOperations As New Thread(AddressOf launchThreadFrmCheckOperations)

Public Shared Sub launchThreadFrmCheckOperations()
     While(True)
         Dim threadForm As New Thread(AddressOf launchFrmCheckOperations)
         threadForm.Start()
         threadForm.Join() '---> Wait until thread is closed
         Thread.Sleep(60000)
     End While
End Sub

Public Shared Sub launchFrmCheckOperations()
    Application.Run(New FormCheckOperations()
End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: This is *not* good programming, the method I described is much more orthadox. I didn't downvote you, but with this answer, I couldn't justify my upvote on your question.

Answer (score 1):

In the FormMain_Closing event, set Visible = False, instantiate and show another form and set e.cancel = True, then put code in the anotherform's closing event to `End` the application.

eg:

```
Private Sub FormMain_FormClosing(sender as Object, e as FormClosingEventArgs) _ 
     Handles FormMain.FormClosing

    Me.Visible = False

    Dim anotherForm as New AnotherForm()
    anotherForm.Show()

    e.Cancel = True

End Sub
```